# How to query state stored aggregate without view table in axon framework?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, axon

I have a state stored aggregate which uses generic jpa repository. I do not want to apply cqrs on this aggregate so that I want to query directly this table to get all aggregates or filter by fields. This is my aggregate repository configuration;

```
fun rewardRepository(): Repository<Reward> =
    GenericJpaRepository.builder(Reward::class.java)
        .entityManagerProvider(entityManagerProvider)
        .eventBus(eventBus)
        .build()
```

How can I query this table by using spring data jpa?

Comment: Duplicate of a question on this forum - https://discuss.axoniq.io/t/how-to-query-state-stored-aggregate/3342